# Just about code formatting

Tags: php, c, drupal-modules

In some forum it's very simple to format your code: like for example www.dreamincode.net

please use code tags when posting

[code] paste your code between these tags [/code]

I do not do that properly, I would like to know how to do this correctly.

Comment: Looks like he's asking about how to do his own code-formatting thing for his site, or how to use another site, or something. As evidenced by his other questions, he knows how to format code here.  With that said, though, that is a kinda odd combination of tags.

Comment: @cHao: yeah, ambiguous question. Re-adjusted my answer to cover BBCode and Markdown accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is commonly called **BBCode** (as in bulletin-board-code).
You'd want a **BBCode to HTML converter** (like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php)) combined with a (javascript) **code highlighter**, (something like [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter)).

Oh, and just in case: **Regex is not a valid solution** for converting BBCode to HTML.

If you want **Stackoverflow**-style code/post formatting you'll want to look into **[Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)** (or **[PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/)**, more specifically).

In Markdown (as on Stackoverflow) you'd then enclose your inline code in backticks like `your code here`, which would result in: `your code here`.

Or you'd prefix your block code with four spaces resulting in:

```
This is
a block
of code
```

Consult [Stackoverflow's Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for further details
(which should also be visible on the right while composing a question).

As for Stackoverflow itself there should also be a { } button right above your editing field, which turns your current selection into formatted code.

*Edit: Your question alone sounded like you're having trouble with SO's code formatting.
Considering your tag choice however it looks like you're actually looking for help on writing your own code formatter. Replaced SO-formatting primer with pointers regarding bbcode/markdown code formattting in PHP.*

Comment: Looks like he's asking about how to do his own code-formatting thing for his site, or how to use another site, or something.  As evidenced by his other questions, he knows how to format code here.

Comment: +1 just for escaping backticks :)

Comment: @cHao: yeah, ambiguous question. Re-adjusted my answer to cover BBCode and Markdown accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert your code, highlight it (select the whole code-text with the mouse) and push on the {}-Button.

Comment: OK, finally a normal answer on my question. Thanks for your reply!